# How to fetch specific value from string which are separated by forward slash in Ansible

Tags: json, string, split, ansible

In ansible playbook I have define variable 'datasetInfo' which has below value stored in it

```
"metadata": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.aiplatform.v1.CreateDatasetOperationMetadata",
            "genericMetadata": {
                "createTime": "2021-10-21T19:44:36.212910Z",
                "updateTime": "2021-10-21T19:44:36.212910Z"
            }
        },
        "name": "projects/93057109696/locations/us-central1/datasets/4110898054394019840/operations/6109567339060002816"
    }
}
```

now I am trying to retrieve specific value from the string.
I want to retrieve  '4110898054394019840' which is inside 'name' object
I am traying to run this inside my playbook but not getting an answer

```
- name: datset id
  debug : 
    msg : "{{ datasetInfo.json.name.split('/') | tail -n 1 }}"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can retrieve array element by `{{ datasetInfo.json.name.split('/')[4]`

Comment: why [4], shouldn't it be [5] ?

Comment: right, I read a bit too fast, should be 5 indeed

Answer (score 1):

So, in addition to the *almost* correct comment by @frederic-henri I wanted to offer a competing theory for how one might extract that bit of text

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: >-
        {{ datasetInfo.json.name 
        | regex_findall('.*/datasets/([0-9]+)/.*')
        | first }}
```

outputs

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "4110898054394019840"
}
```

but the reason I wanted to offer this alternative to using array subscripting is that unlike `split('/')[4]`, which *assumes* it is the 5th slash delimited item, by using `regex_findall` it offers the reader some context about what the string is supposed to be shaped like, and the part we care about. It also means that if, for reasons beyond one's control, Google were to change that `name` field, it would cause the playbook to immediately stop with an error instead of grabbing whatever happened to be in the 5th slash delimited position and then perhaps only later would some downstream error materialize.

And finally, as one will see by actually *running* Frederic's comment, sometimes doing slash counting does not shake out since `split('/')[4]` is actually `datasets`, not the number (the number is `[5]` of the `split`)